# In an Elixir list, how to get the middle value?

Tags: elixir

I need get a middle value from the list.

How to do it using `list[0]` or `list[3..-1]` in elixir?

e.g:

```
 list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 list[0] [1]
 list[2..-1] [3,4,5,6]
```

And how to do it using `Tuple`?

Answer (score 10):

Using [**`Enum.slice/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#slice/2) you could do :

```
Enum.slice(list, 2..-1) # [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And [**`Enum.take/2`**](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take/2) :

```
Enum.take(list, 1) # [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact middle value (as suggested by the heading of the question), you can do the following:

```
# Given a list: li
midPos = (length(li) -1) |> div 2
Enum.at li, midPos  


# Or in one line 
Enum.at(li,(length(li) -1) |> div 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Enum.fetch`:

```
list = ["A","b","c","d"]

Enum.fetch(list, 1) -> return b
Enum.fetch(list, 3) -> return d
```